# Im facing the issue in #nextjs kindly look into this

Tags: next.js13

I've been trying to open my file using "npm run dev" but it isn't opening and it says [[here are the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RamEx.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDtzK.png)
initially i did after npm run dev ctrl+click which took me to the local host page but the page says
"cant reach the page". please look into the problem

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please give a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)